# Scrollbar with indicators like the visual studio IDE

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I'm wondering if it's possible to add indications or colors at certain points of a `DataGridView` scrollbar like visual studio does with its 'Enhanced' scrollbar.

I'm just trying to find a way to visually inform users of any points of interest within the datagridview that cannot be seen on screen, other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: See this CodeProject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624997/Enhanced-Scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

There's a library you can use for that http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624997/Enhanced-Scrollbar.

It may be overkill but it gives you a good explanation of how to achieve this effect yourself by overriding on paint in a custom user control.

Here's another alternative too. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14801/How-to-skin-scrollbars-for-Panels-in-C